# JavaFX outstanding resource locks detected

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I got the following message after 15 minutes of running my program:

```
Outstanding resource locks detected:
ES2 Vram Pool: 79,079,089 used (29.5%), 79,079,089 managed (29.5%), 268,435,456 total
67 total resources being managed
average resource age is 382.5 frames
10 resources at maximum supported age (14.900000)
9 resources marked permanent (13.400000)
1 resources have had mismatched locks (1.500000)
1 resources locked (1.500000)
39 resources contain interesting data (58.200000)
0 resources disappeared (0.000000)
```

I can't determine what this means and where it came from... I read it is usualy produced by WebView and Canvas. I am using Canvas ...

Should I be worried?

Comment: Either ask this question on the [open-jfx mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev) or [search the existing bug database](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) and comment on related issues or create a new issue.  Either way, you will have a better chance of getting a useful response if you include full environment details and an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You marked you question as javafx-2, you should test against the latest [Java 8 production](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and [Java 8 development](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) releases.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the mailing list. About javafx, I am using javafx 8, I chose the wrong tag, sorry about that... Will fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all those interested, according to [existing bug database](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/) this appears to be a JavaFX Bug [RT-34921](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8097324). [Leonid Popov](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=loneid) mentioned it will be fixed in JavaFX 9, [comment here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8097324?focusedCommentId=13800188&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13800188). So I guess we wait for this bug to be fixed. :)
Note: it should be fixed starting with Java 8u60 (backport).